# How to interact with SSRS programmatically

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I working on a web project that needs to manage an SSRS server. Currently, I want to be able to upload a file to it but would like to do more in the future.

I've been doing research to find libraries or something that will allow me to do it but have only found https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most commonly done using the web service exposed by SSRS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx